# Forge viewer cache issue

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative

I am using this Node.js Forge sample to check the [Forge workflow](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/learn.forge.viewmodels/tree/nodejs)

When a model with the same name as another is uploaded to the bucket, it is overwritten but when it is translated older model is displayed in the Forge viewer.
I have set xAdsForce to True to enable re-translation at Forge end. But the issue with browser-side cache still persists.

This article -- [AUTODESK](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/i-make-changes-and-nothing-happens) mentions to set the HTTP request headers, but where do I exactly set them in this code -- [on GITHUB](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/learn.forge.viewmodels/blob/nodejs/public/js/ForgeViewer.js) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[At this line](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/learn.forge.viewmodels/blob/nodejs/routes/modelderivative.js#L53), pass `xAdsForce: true`. It tells the translation to override existing translations. See [SDK documentation](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-api-nodejs-client/blob/master/docs/DerivativesApi.md#translate) and [endpoint documentation](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/job-POST/). You can also delete existing manifest (aka translations) before posting a new translation.

**Update**

You can specify the expiration header with (between lines 29 & 30 on the [mentioned sample](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/learn.forge.viewmodels/blob/nodejs/public/js/ForgeViewer.js)):

```
Autodesk.Viewing.endpoint.HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS['If-Modified-Since'] = 'Sat, 29 Oct 1994 19:43:31 GMT';
```

Applies to the latest Viewer version `v6`

Comment: Yes, I have done the same in Node. Js. I am actually confused about the HTTP request headers part at front-end js code, specifically ForgeViewer.js file.

Comment: From what you described (upload a different file with the same name to a bucket), it's most likely the `x-ads-force` header I mentioned. If the problem persists, maybe clear cache on the browser

Comment: I made the required changes in Node.Js. The browser side part remains. The updated model is dispayed in incognito or private mode properly. Apparently, it is not possible to programmatically clear browser cache. So, I am curious about the viewer cache clearing trick in the article linked in my question.

Comment: Updated my answer.